# What is a random seed in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a coin class for my teachers CoinTester.java program. I've written it and it compiles and executes perfectly. THe only problem is that he wants my results to match his exactly. I don't understand how that is possible because I have to use math.random for the flip() method. I was reading over his notes, trying to understand, and it says that he seeded his solution with 17. What does that mean and how do to reproduce the same results as him?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Most "pseudo-random number generators" can accept a "seed", which is a starting value for the RNG.  If you use the same RNG as he did with the same seed then you will get the exact same sequence of "random" numbers.

Comment: However, you can't set the seed for [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()). If he means the class [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) then you can seed it with [`new Random(long seed)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)). (Hint: check out these links.)

Comment: If the object was for your program to have the same output that his does, I suggest you copy his output to a `System.out.println()` and win.

Comment: So you may need to clarify with him whether he wants you to use `Math.random()` (in which case he can't require it be seeded with 17 and therefore can't require that your results match his) or an instance of the class `Random` (in which case, see above). Main point: you need to speak with him.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Thank you! Those links helped and explained a lot.

Answer (score -2):

He is probably sending 17 to the Random constructor, which makes the output always be the same.